# Get 850MHz 3G working on Samsung S5 Active

Tags: 3g, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I have Samsung S5 Active. It seems that it never get the 3G signal, only 2G.

After some research I found that 850Mhz is disabled in my phone, I tried to enabled it with the code: *#197328640# but no luck. This code seems to work only with S5 but not with S5 Active. I don't have even DEBUG SCREEN menu if I enter this code.

Any suggestion how can I enable 850 3G in my phone?

I also tried to connect to my phone from terminal:

```
$ adb shell
shell@android:/ $ am start -n com.android.settings/.BandMode
```

After entering these commands, I got to the menu in my phone:

```
Set GSM/UMTS Band:
```

but there were no options to chose. I believe somehting is blocking me from changing the band.

Please help, I can't use 3G until I fix it, it seems that mine other chinese phone works much better than Samsung S5 Active.

Answer (score 0):

If the underlying baseband does not support 850 mhz it's not going to work.
Also, if you have a very old SIM it probably isn't going to work.

I believe the software can also prevent you to change the preference.

Maybe upgrade your baseband (radio) after rooting your phone. Maybe a factory upgrade will also do the trick, but I'm not sure. See http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2794087 to root and be able to flash roms.

Personally, I'd try for a refund or return, try to let the store fix this issue. 3G is on the carton after all?

Comment: The phone is new (Samsung S5 Active) and it supports this band, the sim is 6 months old, I don't think it is a issue, because it works on my cheap Chinese phone.
Also I found how people fix it on Samsung S5, but my, S5 Active version has some difference comparing to traditional S5

Comment: According to other posts, AT&T seems to deactivate in purpose 850 3G as they don't use it.